# Simple buffering duplex stream in Node - how to?

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming, node-streams

I'm trying to implement a duplex stream with a buffering capabilities.

It should accumulate chunks of data until there's enough them, and only then send them further.

It can be used, for example, when playing streamed audio/video data: one doesn't simply get frames in time, right?

Below is my silly attempt to create such a buffering duplex stream. There's a source stream, which sends `x\n` characters to the buffering stream, which in its turn should send data further to `process.stdout`.

Alas, it doesn't work. Specifically, the `read()` function doesn't seem to have any ways to **pause** or to **stop**, like:

*"Hey, I don't have any data for you now, come back later"*.

Nah, once I return `undefined` or `null`, the story ends and nothing comes out to the stdout.

```js
var {Readable, Duplex} = require('stream');

// Source stream, seeds: x\n, x\n, x\n, ...
let c = 10;
var rs = new Readable({
  read () {
    if (c > 0) {
      c--;
      console.log('rs reading:', 'x');
      this.push('x\n');
    } 
    else {
      this.push(null)
    }
  },
});

// Buffering duplex stream
// I want it to cache 3 items and only then to proceed
const queue = [];
const limit = 3;
var ds = new Duplex({
  writableHighWaterMark: 0,
  write (chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log('ds writing:', chunk, 'paused: ', ds.isPaused());
    queue.push(chunk);
    callback();
  },
  readableHighWaterMark: 0,
  read () {
    // We don't want to output anything
    // until there's enough elements in the `queue`.
    if (queue.length >= limit) {
      const chunk = queue.shift();
      console.log('ds reading:', chunk);
      this.push(chunk);
    }
    else {
      // So how to wait here?
      this.push(undefined)
    }
  },
});

// PROBLEM: nothing is coming out of the "ds" and printed on the stdout
rs.pipe(ds).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Here is my repl: https://repl.it/@OnkelTem/BufferingStream1-1#index.js

I checked the state of the duplex and it's not even in the paused state. So it's not paused, it's flowing, and yet — returns nothing.

I also spent a couple of hours re-reading documentation on the Node streams, but it doesn't actually feel like it was created for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

A buffering stream is just a type of a transform stream. If I understand what you're trying to do properly, the implementation shouldn't be any more complicated than this:

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');

const DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

class BufferingTransform extends Transform {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    super(options);

    this.capacity = options.capacity || DEFAULT_CAPACITY ;
    this.pending = [] ;

    return;
  }

  get atCapacity() {
    return this.pending.length >= this.capacity;
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, cb) {

    if ( this.atCapacity ) {
      this.push( ...this.pending.shift() );
    }

    this.pending.push( [chunk, encoding] );

    cb();
  }

  _flush(cb) {

    while (this.pending.length > 0) {
      this.push( ...this.pending.shift() );
    }

    cb();
  }

}
```

Once you have that, it should be just a matter of piping your source through the `BufferingStream and reading from the` BufferingStream`:

```
async function readFromSource() {
  const source = openSourceForReading();
  const buffer = new BufferingStream();

  source.pipe(buffer);

  for await (const chunk of buffer) {
    console.log(chunk);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, that's exactly what I needed, but instead of the Duplex you use Transform stream. Good! A sandbox with your version: https://repl.it/@OnkelTem/BufferingStream1-2 . And one more, without classes: https://repl.it/@OnkelTem/BufferingStream1-3
And still it's interesting how to do the same with just Duplex stream.

Comment: A Transform stream is just a special kind of Duplex stream which handles some of the logic for you, so their solution does use a Duplex stream ;)

Comment: @tjjfvi - yeah, that I know. My initial difficulty was implementing `read()` method of a [more generic] Duplex stream. Basically I don't know how to "wait" there, as there's no any `callback`. So I'm curious how would it look like, a Duplex stream doing exactly what Nicholas's Transform one doing.

Comment: I have one idea. Implement all the logic inside `write()`, and do trivial reading in the `read()`. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @Onkeltem — a `Transform` subtypes `Duplex`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation using async iterables:

```js
function bufferStream(stream, bufferCount){
    stream = normalizeAsyncIterable(stream);
    const iterator = stream[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
    const queue = []

    while(queue.length < bufferCount)
        queue.push(iterator.next());

    return normalizeAsyncIterable({
        [Symbol.asyncIterator]: () => ({
            next: async () => {
                const promise = queue.shift() ?? iterator.next();
                while(queue.length < bufferCount)
                    queue.push(iterator.next());
                return promise;
            }
        })
    });
}

// Ensures that calls to .next() while the generator is paused are handled correctly
async function* normalizeAsyncIterable(iterable){
    for await(const value of iterable)
        yield value;
}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgEZhCApgJwMow5YCGAtgDwAqAfABQDOhJpAXMgIL0Ce0AkjLmKoANlirUANGgzYcAYQSQYbCGFKpcASgDewZPuSMiZZAF5kEBDlLFhcAF5ZOPKP0EisDJmU0BuPQZQSIzIcAI4xDBWZobepADaeFzqCMIAdMTcfOGRVgC6tH4B+kEQIQCOYFhVbAAKOAikcPRibhFROABKWPRgwjDi1PF5McPAxcgA7gAWcKK0ldVYaaIQAOYw08jk0pi4CkqaEwbIi1VpAA5g9NO0YYIdaRBYAB4whUUTRDBgOCiW1lsDicWVcOQ8tF0JxOiWSqFSGVBbVyODybEKZmoyEhx2h+mebzYmRc2M0mOQULxVJKwRgyAuDSaLRiZ2WNzgIHeZIA-NzQjlHgSuf5qdSZnNPKyVlh1pttrtZAcIDAjqK1acqucrjc7gKrE9Xlyiurod9figGY1mlgReqAL64-R21UGZ3+B3AAD0nuQAFEyr8eshNpFkFBbMJ6MGEMgDW8MeLRMHplhkGsZQ9os16cRrlgACbIYhEZDTYgQfOiQtBHBEWDCLjAYnQZDgaDwJAAKgsVhsdkczmy7lE4l1w6wbEHYPH4k0k6R4JHNEp+hA0WIk2IYVopRCADdbFVkAgQPzxy68Vw4FhhIWD8Iqu7xt7kJQejBxs2oK3ILBEBBu3zSJiDwRQcCgTwdAmNccFoUQ6TgGIAAZfFCeUAEYUNCABqbCoOpDctzpehRCwC5aAAViQ40qV3VJlmEBA1loAADK8b2raZIAAa2QAASbQ4DtFiL2hdjb1CCYHQ9XdiNIi4YloUh6BUNQNBwMlTCxZ5JmQeorRaWgcHJFoYEoOBSCwRR3hwKRlM0T5aC-UlyV0CY6NEFYmNoAAiRhixgHyjnc2kFVwAsCGMUgYnQPZ8DiWggJgECwIgwopAAZk+E4YKLTdt1ksMuIgXiTzCoh80i5h8KpQiwkMeTaEw6jbTxDyGO8li1gQOkoGK3iBL6njhNEj1nUKYAgA)